# Selecting from view produces syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dumb question. Here is a small database:

```
CREATE TABLE tmptable (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `p_id` VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO tmptable
  (`id`, `p_id`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'null'),
  ('2', '1'),
  ('3', '1'),
  ('4', '2'),
  ('5', '2');
```

Then by submitting:

```
create view root as
select id from tmptable where p_id is null

select * from root
```

I got:

> Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from root' at line 1

The error is generated by https://www.db-fiddle.com/

My intention was to create a view that can be reused multiple times in one query code script submission. I thought the view would act like a temporary variable, and I wanted to use as little memory as possible. How can I do that?

Comment: Fiddle is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creation of view and doing a select on that view after creation is two different queries.
Give semicolon after writing the DDL for view.

```
create view root as
select id from tmptable where p_id is null;

select * from root;
```

As a result you shouldn't get any record, as the `null` is actual NULL object and `'null'` in the table is a string.